# Specifying sorting direction in psycopg2 by parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to specify in a query the sorting direction (ASC/DESC) by parameter, but psycopg2 throws an error as I'm sending a string as a replacement for a reserved word:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'ASC'"
```

this is my code:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM foo
        ORDER BY
            CASE %(order_by)s
                WHEN 'a' THEN textfield_a %(sort_direction)s
                WHEN 'b' THEN textfield_b %(sort_direction)s
                ELSE 'c' THEN textfield_c
            END""", dict(order_by='a', sort_direction='ASC'))
```

Is there a way in psycopg2 to do this?

Of course a possible solution would be to concatenate both parameters and duplicate the condtions like:

```
ORDER BY
CASE %(order_by_concatenation)s
    WHEN 'a:ASC' THEN textfield_a ASC
    WHEN 'a:DESC' THEN textfield_a DESC
    WHEN 'b:ASC' THEN textfield_b ASC
    WHEN 'b:DESC' THEN textfield_b DESC
    ELSE 'c' THEN textfield_c
END
```

but I don't like this idea, as in the future I might have many more conditions...

Comment: where is `order_by` coming from? a sql query? or is it passed in by python?

Comment: You will need to use string interpolation. Parameter substitution is only possible with literals. Unfortunately.

Comment: @scytale yes, it's the "order by" part of a select

Comment: that's not what I asked

Comment: the variable `order_by` is what I asked about

Comment: it's one of the parameters passed to the cursor, it's passed by python.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use string interpolation. Parameter substitution is only possible with literals. Unfortunately.
 -  Craig Ringer

```
cursor.execute("""
SELECT * FROM foo
    ORDER BY
        CASE %(order_by)s
            WHEN 'a' THEN textfield_a {0}
            WHEN 'b' THEN textfield_b {0}
            ELSE 'c' THEN textfield_c
        END""".format('ASC'), dict(order_by='a'))
```

You need to be **VERY** careful about your sort order variable because it can be SQL injection attacked.

Comment: I used string interpolation as Craig suggested, but using a default value if anything provided is not in a predefined set of possible accepted values, to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an if statement to avoid SQL injections. Eg.

```
def runSQL(order = "DESC"):
    order = order.upper()
    Sorting = ["ASD", "DESC"]

    if not (order in Sorting) or type(order) != str:
        order = "DESC"    

    results = None
    sql = ""
    if order == "DESC":
        sql = 'select * from public.mytable ORDER BY id DESC;'
    else:
        sql = 'select * from public.mytable ORDER BY id ASC;'

    conn, res2 = psycopg2.connect(f"dbname={dbname} user={user} host={host} password={password}") 
    with conn.cursor as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
        results = cur.fetchall()

    return results
```